# Add event to google calendar using API

Tags: php, api, events, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm adding events from my web app using this example provided by google:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events

Everything works great, but when I need to add an event to my calendar I need approve OAuth 2.0 (60 in 60min).

My final objective is filled one form with the subject, date, description, etc..and send to google calendar without request nothing to the user.

Can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by _"60 in 60min"_? If you want to omit the Oauth totally, then no, it can't be done. The user needs to authenticate his account before google lets you update it.

Comment: "60 in 60min" is the time to access_token expire. And if only me can add events?

Comment: Ah. ok. But now I have to ask, what do you mean by _"if only me can add events"_? It you have a valid access token, (you can store it in a session and reuse it so the user doesn't need to re-authenticate, during that session) you can add events, if you don't, then you obviously can't modify anything on that users account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. I want say, for example, only admin can insert events. I can insert events like i said before, my question is only about authentication. According to their answers it is not possible to do.

Comment: you should be saving the refresh token returned when the user first authenticated your application then when the access token expires after 60 minutes you request an new access token.

Comment: @DaltmTo humm, so i save the token in database and after 60 minutes i need do same thing? Or what's your advice?