# Ask authorization to use only first time to use calendar

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I wanna only ask to the user one time to access the account. I have the token but after 3600 seconds the token expires.

This is my code (working) "inside" a framework. Someone can tell how can i do it?

```
public function actionEvent() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar Event");
    $client->setAuthConfig(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/calendar/client_secret.json');
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $calendar_service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
                ..events here..
        ));
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        $event = $calendar_service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
        var_dump($event->htmlLink);
    } else {
        $redirect_uri = $this->redirect(['pop/callback']);
    }
}

public function actionCallback() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar Event");
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/calendar/client_secret.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/pop/callback');
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $this->redirect($auth_url);
    } else {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $this->redirect(['pop/event']);
    }
}
```

Inside of session i have:

```
array (size=3)
  '__flash' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '__id' => int 1
  'access_token' => 
    array (size=4)
      'access_token' => string 'ya29.Ci-sf-asdfsadfsdfsd' (length=71)
      'token_type' => string 'Bearer' (length=6)
      'expires_in' => int 3599
      'created' => int 1479326378
```

Thank you

Comment: Basically the same question as your other one from earlier today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625179/add-event-to-google-calendar-using-api

Comment: Yes, but now with code.

Comment: you can renew the token

Comment: but how? And i need store the first token in some place?

Comment: yes you store the first token after that you just use the stored token to get a new one. you can do that an infinite amount of time (untill the user removes permission)

Comment: What i need to store? _access_token_ (string) or complete array(json encoded)? And after that, what i need to generate a new? Which method i need to use?

Answer (score 1):

The very first time your application is authenticating the user, you are returned a refresh token inside `$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();`. That is when you need to get the refresh token `$refrshToken = $_SESSION['access_token']['refresh_token];` so you can use it after 3600 seconds to refresh the access token. If you did not save the refresh token the first time your app authenticated, then you have to set the approval prompt to *force* `$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');`, or alternatively you can delete the app from your connected apps and sites https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?utm_source=OGB

You can try modifying your actionCallback function like this

```
public function actionCallback() {

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar Event");
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/calendar/client_secret.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/pop/callback');
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $this->redirect($auth_url);

    } else {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

        //Save refresh token to cookie
        setcookie("autorefresh", $_SESSION['access_token']['refresh_token], 2000000000); 

        $this->redirect(['pop/event']);

    }
}
```

And then try modifying your actionEvent function like this

```
public function actionEvent() {

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar Event");
    $client->setAuthConfig(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/calendar/client_secret.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

    if (isset($_COOKIE['autorefresh'])){

        if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        }

        if( time() - $_SESSION['access_token']['created'] >= 3600){

            $refreshtoken = $_COOKIE['autorefresh'];           

            $client->refreshToken($refreshtoken);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); 
        } 

        $calendar_service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
            ..events here..
        ));
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        $event = $calendar_service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
        var_dump($event->htmlLink);
    } else {
        actionCallback();
    }
}
```

Just PLEASE BARE IN MIND THAT SAVING THE REFRESH TOKEN TO A COOKIE IS NOT RECOMMENDED! This is only so you can test how the refresh token system works. I would strongly recommend you to save it to a file or to a sql database. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Morfinismo. I solved my problem from another way. I'm saving the data on database. I needed too clean all session variable to get refresh_token. (unset($_SESSSION);).

Comment: I have one more question. 
Each time that i wanna access webapp from different device, i need accept? (using same login account and same gmail account, only changing device/browser)

Comment: If you are saving the access information on a database, this shouldn't happen. You are only prompted to accept if you don't have the access code to request the refresh token.